# Android Visualizer loses headphones

Tags: android, headset, visualizer, headphones

My Android apps are audio players with built in music visualizations. They can use Android Visualizer class to get sound data. But unfortunately it does not contain any music if headhones are connected. It takes sound only from microhone but not audio mixer out. Of course in Visualizer constructor I use session ID == 0.

```
    private static int initVisualizer() {
    viz = new Visualizer( 0 );
    if( viz == null )
        return 0;
    .......
```

Docs tell that means Visualizer will take output mix. But this is wrong - it takes microphone signal. And of course it uses headset microphone, not device's. Therefore my visualizations stop working if user connects headset or external speaker. How to solve this?

Comment: If you're visualizing the audio from your own apps, can't you just use whatever `getAudioSessionId()` returns for the `AudioTrack`/`MediaPlayer` instead of 0?

Comment: Regarding _"it takes microphone signal"_, that sounds like a bug in the implementation on that device. Have you verified that it actually _is_ recording via the microphone? For example, IIRC, if you or the system enables an effect on a specific session, then all effects (e.g. the visualizer) on session 0 will be suspended.

Comment: The program definitely gets signal from microphone when headset is connected. But I cannot tell which one microphone it hears - on headset wire or own built in. Both are very sensitive.

Comment: About playing music with connected headset - the program gets it exactly. But in all my devices with headset the level in Visualizer appears VERY low. I had multiple level to big enough number to see visual effects working. Without headset this is not needed - received visualizer level is big enough.

Comment: There was an error in my code... Actually it did not get Visualizer data but the microphone data in all cases. After I fixed it - I have got another strange result. On Android 4.1 and 6.0 the Visualizer( 0 ) gives proper data in all cases. App works fine. On Android 7.0 it works differently depending from player. If I start some 3d party player - in my app Visualizer gives proper music data. But if I start my internal app MediaPlayer - Visualizer does not give data. That means the call to viz.getWaveForm() returns false. Why in Android 7 the Visualizer(0) does not give ALL output music data?

Comment: Similar app assembled for target API level 23 works properly. But app with problem was assembled for target API level 26.

Comment: Permissions were requested and granted as required for this API. Otherwise Visualizer wouldn't work at all. But it works, for example when system sounds emitted. It only does not capture sound from MediaPlayer in same app. May be cause MediaPlayer instance is created _after_ Visualizer instance. In prev APIs this worked well.

Comment: In case of having your own `MediaPlayer`, why can't you just use that `MediaPlayer`'s specific audio session ID as I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: I cannot start MediaPlayer _before_ Visualizer. This is limited by application architecture and initialization sequence. MediaPlayer depends from other app parts and can be only started _after_ Visualizer. To start it before Visualizer I have to completely redesign application. That means I need it create from 0.